# Compare 2 uneven size Pandas DataFrames for matching values and combine together, then substitute the NaN value by the closest data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and Stackoverflow. I have a problem with handling the data. I have 2 sets of data with different size. df1 has a size of 1000 and df2 has a size of 100000. Here are the samples of df1 and df2.

```
df1=
        Date                 x     y   
    0   2020-01-01 01:01    1.1   2.4 
    1   2020-01-01 01:05    4.2   5.5  
    2   2020-01-01 01:08    7.3   8.6  

 

df2=
        Date                 x     y
    0   2020-01-01 01:00    NaN   NaN
    1   2020-01-01 01:01    NaN   NaN
    2   2020-01-01 01:02    NaN   NaN
    3   2020-01-01 01:03    NaN   NaN
    4   2020-01-01 01:04    NaN   NaN
    5   2020-01-01 01:05    NaN   NaN
    6   2020-01-01 01:06    NaN   NaN
    7   2020-01-01 01:07    NaN   NaN 
    8   2020-01-01 01:08    NaN   NaN
    9   2020-01-01 01:09    NaN   NaN
   10   2020-01-01 01:10    NaN   NaN
```

What I would like to do is to combine them together as a new data frame, if `df1['Date']=df2['Date']`, df3 will be shown as follow.

```
df3= 
        Date                 x     y
    0   2020-01-01 01:00    NaN   NaN     
    1   2020-01-01 01:01    1.1   2.4 
    2   2020-01-01 01:02    NaN   NaN
    3   2020-01-01 01:03    NaN   NaN
    4   2020-01-01 01:04    NaN   NaN
    5   2020-01-01 01:05    4.2   5.5  
    6   2020-01-01 01:06    NaN   NaN
    7   2020-01-01 01:07    NaN   NaN 
    8   2020-01-01 01:08    7.3   8.6  
    9   2020-01-01 01:09    NaN   NaN
   10   2020-01-01 01:10    NaN   NaN
```

Then, the NaN values will be equal to the closest value above

```
df3=
        Date                 x     y
    0   2020-01-01 01:00    NaN   NaN     
    1   2020-01-01 01:01    1.1   2.4 
    2   2020-01-01 01:02    1.1   2.4 
    3   2020-01-01 01:03    1.1   2.4 
    4   2020-01-01 01:04    1.1   2.4 
    5   2020-01-01 01:05    4.2   5.5  
    6   2020-01-01 01:06    4.2   5.5  
    7   2020-01-01 01:07    4.2   5.5  
    8   2020-01-01 01:08    7.3   8.6  
    9   2020-01-01 01:09    7.3   8.6  
   10   2020-01-01 01:10    7.3   8.6
```

Thx a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congratulations on your first post. What have you tried? Add your code and any errors/output to your question and that will help others find solutions to your problem. It may be helpful to you to read: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't get why `2020-09-01 01:08` in `df1` is matched with `2020-01-01 01:08` in `df2`?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. All the dates are 2020-01-01. I have reedited the questions

Answer (score 1):

One way, would be to use [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#merging-together-values-within-series-or-dataframe-columns) on your complete df (assuming it includes all indices). Then use `fillna` to get the previous values for all your missings:

```py
    a = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "date": pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", periods=3),
            "x": [1, np.nan, 3],
            "y": [5, np.nan, 6],
        }
    ).set_index("date")
    
    b = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "date": pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", periods=5),
            "x": [np.nan] * 5,
            "y": [np.nan] * 5,
        }
    ).set_index("date")
    print(a, b)
```

```
| date                |   x |   y |
|:--------------------|----:|----:|
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |   1 |   5 |
| 2020-01-02 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 2020-01-03 00:00:00 |   3 |   6 |


| date                |   x |   y |
|:--------------------|----:|----:|
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 2020-01-02 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 2020-01-04 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
| 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | nan | nan |
```

```py
    b.update(a)
    b = b.fillna(method="ffill")
    print(b)
```

```
| date                |   x |   y |
|:--------------------|----:|----:|
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |   1 |   5 |
| 2020-01-02 00:00:00 |   1 |   5 |
| 2020-01-03 00:00:00 |   3 |   6 |
| 2020-01-04 00:00:00 |   3 |   6 |
| 2020-01-05 00:00:00 |   3 |   6 |
```

Comment: Thx for your comment! Will have a try tmr to see if this works for me